# Rolling multvariate regressions

Tags: r, nested-lists, rolling-computation

Hello I am attempting to do the fama macbeth two step regression with rolling windows.

My rolling window is 60 months. Funds to regress go from 8:564 (the dependant variables total of 556 funds) in my dataframe, independant variables are between 2:7.
The total months are 115, thus we can have coefficients for 115-60= 55 months.

I inspired my self from another post and obtain the following code that works to obtain coefficients for each time period, each fund and each factors :

```
    library(tidyverse)

mydata = read.csv("test.csv")
y <- map(8:564,
         function(i) {
           map(1:55,
               function(j, i) {
                 lm(mydata[j:(60+j), i] ~ .,  data =mydata[j:(60+j), 2:7])[[1]][2:7]
               }, i = i)
         })
```

However now my problem is, that I have a nested list Y where each y[i] (i= each fund) is a list of 55 vectors containg the coefficients of the factors for each month.

I need to be able to average each factor by fund, for example for the factor "SMB", average the SMB coefficients of the 55 periods to obtain only a single coefficient for that fund for the SMB factor.

What I am looking to obtain is the average six factors by fund for the 55 month period. Having a data frame with the 6 different factors as rows and 556 columns( the different funds) where the rows would contain the average factor for that fund.

Here is the dput of my original data frame, I reduced the number of funds to 4 to have usable dataframe the code above would just need to modify "8:564" by "8:12"

````
    dput(testdataframe)
structure(list(Date = structure(1:115, .Label = c("2010-05-31", 
"2010-06-30", "2010-07-30", "2010-08-31", "2010-09-30", "2010-10-29", 
"2010-11-30", "2010-12-31", "2011-01-31", "2011-02-28", "2011-03-31", 
"2011-04-29", "2011-05-31", "2011-06-30", "2011-07-29", "2011-08-31", 
"2011-09-30", "2011-10-31", "2011-11-30", "2011-12-30", "2012-01-31", 
"2012-02-29", "2012-03-30", "2012-04-30", "2012-05-31", "2012-06-29", 
"2012-07-31", "2012-08-31", "2012-09-28", "2012-10-31", "2012-11-30", 
"2012-12-31", "2013-01-31", "2013-02-28", "2013-03-28", "2013-04-30", 
"2013-05-31", "2013-06-28", "2013-07-31", "2013-08-30", "2013-09-30", 
"2013-10-31", "2013-11-29", "2013-12-31", "2014-01-31", "2014-02-28", 
"2014-03-31", "2014-04-30", "2014-05-30", "2014-06-30", "2014-07-31", 
"2014-08-29", "2014-09-30", "2014-10-31", "2014-11-28", "2014-12-31", 
"2015-01-30", "2015-02-27", "2015-03-31", "2015-04-30", "2015-05-29", 
"2015-06-30", "2015-07-31", "2015-08-31", "2015-09-30", "2015-10-30", 
"2015-11-30", "2015-12-31", "2016-01-29", "2016-02-29", "2016-03-31", 
"2016-04-29", "2016-05-31", "2016-06-30", "2016-07-29", "2016-08-31", 
"2016-09-30", "2016-10-31", "2016-11-30", "2016-12-30", "2017-01-31", 
"2017-02-28", "2017-03-31", "2017-04-28", "2017-05-31", "2017-06-30", 
"2017-07-31", "2017-08-31", "2017-09-29", "2017-10-31", "2017-11-30", 
"2017-12-29", "2018-01-31", "2018-02-28", "2018-03-29", "2018-04-30", 
"2018-05-31", "2018-06-29", "2018-07-31", "2018-08-31", "2018-09-28", 
"2018-10-31", "2018-11-30", "2018-12-31", "2019-01-31", "2019-02-28", 
"2019-03-29", "2019-04-30", "2019-05-31", "2019-06-28", "2019-07-31", 
"2019-08-30", "2019-09-30", "2019-10-31", "2019-11-29"), class = "factor"), 
    UME.PROXY = c(-0.000724658, -0.005744157, -0.004059006, 0.000730039, 
    -0.003856785, -0.000343876, -0.003475997, -0.0081364, 0.001128034, 
    -0.002585321, -0.003010976, 0.003096291, -0.006233193, 0.007021689, 
    0.000733877, -0.013827583, 0.001796754, 0.000339051, 0.005640408, 
    0.004518049, -0.008113983, -0.002934056, -0.009942401, 0.002855035, 
    0.004158718, -0.00033229, -0.000882825, -0.004520612, -0.006555119, 
    0.003286183, 0.000956616, -0.002131598, -0.000638275, -0.006032098, 
    0.002373039, -0.003312455, -0.00870683, 0.001287356, -0.016242079, 
    -0.007838342, -0.001569358, -0.009695109, -0.000104717, 0.001128842, 
    -0.008548112, -0.003422785, -0.003710039, -0.003577239, 0.00190479, 
    0.004088383, 0.004170113, 0.006987248, 0.006132453, 0.00118992, 
    -0.001271605, -0.001910165, -0.011094524, -0.005393945, -0.005682147, 
    -0.004076733, -0.001770596, -0.004180218, 0.00731324, -0.014107303, 
    -0.002927917, -0.005206962, -0.003447737, -0.003746203, 0.000128482, 
    0.00332775, -0.006817127, -0.003734958, 0.002575807, 0.009394906, 
    -0.006580909, -0.001998549, 0.003051689, -0.000272597, -0.000130306, 
    -0.006592017, -0.005033978, -0.000904058, -0.002871654, -0.006998141, 
    0.005530449, 0.000458694, -0.006868596, 0.001207348, 0.001653872, 
    0.000547852, 0.000792877, -0.003906205, -0.001693455, -0.010203385, 
    -0.001409528, 0.000815144, -0.00215596, 0.000759584, -0.000333102, 
    -0.009461779, 0.004980961, 0.000438439, 0.000669097, -0.00205561, 
    -0.004706244, -0.002016315, 0.007150693, 0.005616387, 0.004701252, 
    0.003749277, -0.000615109, -0.00252158, -0.003883389, -0.003880969, 
    -0.003469177), SMB = c(-7e-04, -0.0172, -6e-04, 0.0093, 0.0062, 
    0.0107, 0.0218, -0.0022, -0.0109, 0.0208, -0.0117, 0.0023, 
    -0.0124, 0.002, 0.0085, -0.0113, -0.0338, -0.0254, -0.0099, 
    0.0267, 0.0138, 0.0077, 0.0124, 0.0029, -0.0432, -0.0133, 
    5e-04, 0.0167, -0.0058, -0.0244, 0.0249, 0.0065, 0.02, -0.0081, 
    -0.0138, 0.0121, 0.0214, -0.0145, 0.0264, 0.0017, 3e-04, 
    0.0081, 0.0055, 0.0363, 0.0053, 0.0062, -0.0206, -0.006, 
    0.0019, -0.006, -0.0093, -0.0218, -0.0115, -0.0136, 0.023, 
    -0.0155, 0.0087, -0.0032, 0.0207, 0.015, 0.0194, -0.0093, 
    0.0364, 0.0117, -0.0294, 0.0031, 0.0374, -0.0062, 0.0148, 
    0.0179, -0.0056, 0.0141, -0.0224, 0.0151, 0.017, 0.0097, 
    -0.005, 0.01, -0.0082, 0.0212, 2e-04, -0.0128, 0.0194, 3e-04, 
    0.0161, 0.0068, 3e-04, -0.0016, -0.0099, -0.0029, 0.0154, 
    0.0064, 0.011, -0.0056, -0.0071, 0.0108, -0.009, -0.0206, 
    0.0085, -0.0134, -0.0151, -0.0111, -0.0051, 0.0056, -0.0147, 
    -0.018, 0.0014, 0.012, -0.0255, -0.0132, -0.0068, -0.0067, 
    0.0083, 0.0188, 0.027), HML = c(-0.0222, 0.0462, -0.027, 
    -0.0028, 8e-04, -0.0346, 0.0111, 0.0552, 0.007, -0.0183, 
    -0.0068, -0.0228, 0.0011, -0.0405, -0.0374, -0.0179, -0.0109, 
    -0.0326, -0.0098, 0.0094, -0.0037, -0.0156, -0.0418, -0.0248, 
    0.0301, -0.0257, 0.0337, 0.0214, 0.0204, -0.0049, 0.0308, 
    0.0424, -0.0344, -0.0436, 0.0355, 0.0288, -0.0245, 0.0277, 
    0.0057, 0.0131, 0.0439, -0.0055, -0.0022, 0.0248, 0.0064, 
    0.0178, 0.0046, -0.0042, -0.0162, 0.0026, -0.0099, -0.0035, 
    -0.0319, -0.0193, -0.024, -0.0348, 0.0191, -0.0042, 0.0039, 
    -0.0259, 0.0013, -0.0266, -0.0099, -0.0363, -0.0077, -0.028, 
    -0.0125, -0.0149, 0.0038, 0.0118, 0.0335, -0.0287, -0.0164, 
    0.0021, 0.0192, -0.0014, 0.0636, 0.0192, 0.0199, 0.0047, 
    -0.026, 0.005, -0.013, -0.0079, 0.0204, 0.026, -0.007, 0.0047, 
    -0.0012, 0.0128, 0.005, 0.011, -0.0075, -0.0094, 0.015, -0.0498, 
    -0.0156, 0.0041, -0.0264, 0.0233, 0.0148, -0.0057, 0.0095, 
    -0.0096, -0.0122, -0.0232, -0.0105, -0.0154, -0.0132, 4e-04, 
    -0.0191, 0.0308, -0.0051, -0.0229, 0.004), RMW = c(-0.0107, 
    -0.0283, 0.0264, -0.0043, 0.0138, 0.0177, -0.016, -0.0302, 
    0.0046, 0.02, 0.0102, 0.0193, 0.0099, 0.0226, 0.0348, 0.0229, 
    0.0121, 0.0269, 0.0036, -0.0207, -0.008, 0.0096, 0.03, 0.0259, 
    -0.0047, 0.0246, -0.0194, -0.0152, -0.0112, 0.0056, -0.0073, 
    -0.0333, 0.0207, 0.0221, -0.0108, -0.0107, 0.0227, -0.006, 
    2e-04, -0.0094, -0.0176, 0.0067, 0.004, -0.0119, 0.007, 0.011, 
    0.0044, 0.0069, 0.0207, -0.0163, 0.0023, -0.0044, 0.0233, 
    0.0067, 0.0157, 0.0284, -0.0197, 0, 3e-04, 5e-04, -0.0014, 
    0.0093, 0.0079, 0.027, 0.0198, 0.0303, 0.0067, 0.0247, 0.0064, 
    0.0074, -0.0188, 0.0176, 0.0325, 7e-04, -0.0192, 0.0032, 
    -0.0385, -0.0153, -0.0091, -0.0024, 0.0273, 0.0012, 0.016, 
    0.0122, -0.0201, -0.0224, 0.0145, 0.0033, 0.001, -0.0037, 
    -0.0075, -0.0213, 0.0019, 0.0145, -0.0052, 0.0238, -0.0016, 
    -0.0053, 0.0087, -0.0053, -0.0037, 0.0078, 0.007, 0.0166, 
    -2e-04, 0.0123, 0.0034, -0.0059, 0.0149, -0.0117, 0.0088, 
    -0.0047, 0.0127, 0.0132, -0.0039), CMA = c(-0.0111, 0.0097, 
    -0.0214, 0.0155, -0.0033, 0.0011, 0.0112, 0.0137, 4e-04, 
    -0.0037, 0.0074, -0.0067, -0.0064, -0.0048, -0.0112, 0.0144, 
    -0.03, -0.0042, 0.0025, -0.0209, -0.0077, 0.0164, -0.0067, 
    0.0141, 0.0202, -0.022, 0.0154, 0.0082, -0.003, -0.0087, 
    0.009, 0.0181, -0.0136, -0.0033, 0.0128, -0.0016, 0.0039, 
    0.003, 0.0093, 0.0153, 0.0175, 0.0063, 0.0029, 0.0206, 0.0095, 
    0.0016, -0.0112, -0.0039, -0.0096, 0.004, -0.0077, 0.0039, 
    -0.0053, 0.0024, -0.0194, -0.0106, -0.0013, 0.0079, -0.0041, 
    -0.0066, -0.0022, -0.0076, -0.009, -0.0098, -6e-04, -0.0212, 
    -0.0165, 0.0228, 0.0088, -0.0113, 0.009, -0.0048, 0.0282, 
    -0.0086, -2e-04, 3e-04, 0.0295, 0.0187, 0.0104, 0.0018, -0.0132, 
    -0.0028, -0.0132, -0.0069, 0.0079, 0.0034, -4e-04, -0.005, 
    -0.0032, 0.0089, 0.0034, 0.0091, -0.0025, -0.0137, 0.0043, 
    -0.0242, -0.0057, -0.0086, -0.0174, 0.0064, 0.0115, 0.0046, 
    0, -0.0128, -0.0016, -0.0087, -0.0029, 1e-04, 0.001, 5e-04, 
    -2e-04, 0.0125, -0.0159, -0.0165, 0.0014), MKT.New = c(-0.048312632, 
    -0.005699491, 0.049696506, -0.012657156, 0.033270451, 0.024780083, 
    -0.013329446, 0.051789232, 0.017089348, 0.025164953, -0.03480018, 
    0.033030937, -0.002026571, -0.027451865, -0.025288067, -0.101951761, 
    -0.044615249, 0.078324394, -0.010633736, 0.02097599, 0.038118686, 
    0.040562643, -0.001414649, -0.016842437, -0.060758886, 0.051563965, 
    0.042065165, 0.020144668, 0.008691674, 0.007331822, 0.021910407, 
    0.014465086, 0.028011002, 0.009293811, 0.016253924, 0.016268534, 
    0.019182709, -0.051096826, 0.050984774, -0.005847953, 0.044184492, 
    0.038345817, 0.010295931, 0.010191005, -0.01769965, 0.047721542, 
    -0.008100018, 0.018758506, 0.025209108, -0.004362606, -0.015421385, 
    0.020055485, 0.003569607, -0.018292683, 0.031688521, -0.01410335, 
    0.072317087, 0.069232797, 0.016618996, 4.85e-05, 0.014212262, 
    -0.046248027, 0.039915756, -0.084145048, -0.043068499, 0.082861073, 
    0.026726284, -0.052753996, -0.062274698, -0.021951084, 0.013329536, 
    0.019225364, 0.022833821, -0.04254516, 0.035086731, 0.00701888, 
    -0.000324184, -0.008215328, 0.010899183, 0.058436658, -0.00371804, 
    0.029190737, 0.033379694, 0.016871755, 0.015315528, -0.024814936, 
    -0.003723861, -0.007763082, 0.038829325, 0.019479312, -0.020703178, 
    0.007916182, 0.016031416, -0.038650418, -0.020244064, 0.046104084, 
    0.001061424, -0.006914992, 0.031055612, -0.022421323, 0.005250311, 
    -0.053099372, -0.008612348, -0.055295266, 0.061889756, 0.041547069, 
    0.020271848, 0.037769537, -0.049408858, 0.04427325, 0.002977513, 
    -0.014400284, 0.037628124, 0.008578484, 0.026934147), ORAPT.NA.Equity = c(-0.054271897, 
    -0.003267045, 0.024084367, -0.023517952, 0.063844948, 0.047019424, 
    0.006141249, 0.107070193, -0.022053756, -0.012567536, 0.065897466, 
    0.040062493, -0.006759657, -0.0676245, -0.058510022, -0.144597588, 
    -0.017695296, 0.062536614, -0.093590627, 0.026916058, 0.031689619, 
    0.070905698, 0.05548854, -0.037587302, -0.115978361, 0.016865672, 
    -0.025392632, 0.00873494, 0.018214392, 0.017155425, -0.003892172, 
    0.049927641, 0.068642316, -0.000386947, -0.002451613, 0.019143707, 
    -0.005330626, -0.051550338, 0.049239876, 0.020643672, 0.062688442, 
    0.043149308, 0.040344515, 0.010566449, 0.016600194, -0.00837663, 
    -0.011334474, 0.02682241, 0.031177586, -0.017875383, -0.032657306, 
    -0.00322546, 0.01067846, -0.034151547, 0.047845304, 0.01360329, 
    0.006658344, 0.113166598, 0.075109089, 0, -0.034455959, -0.016188176, 
    0.038818182, -0.059595694, -0.04262051, 0.105073872, 0.005629343, 
    0.034461646, -0.046250106, 0.03998227, 0.071690393, 0.010101814, 
    0.007638397, -0.036730228, 0.083887717, 0.042814371, 0.024332472, 
    0.004484619, 0.02183467, 0.056116876, 0.022301228, 0.035156497, 
    0.040131941, 0.08908856, 0.059261256, -0.018224394, 0.013481282, 
    -0.010590402, 0.069031491, 0.024765406, -0.016237138, 0.03584109, 
    0.014961323, -0.03030303, 0.001270708, -0.011750881, -0.005897741, 
    -0.057461365, 0.014263959, 0.002202092, -0.014531835, -0.087817979, 
    -0.001277707, -0.080598509, 0.111017, 0.012306687, -0.006347499, 
    0.068211347, -0.089397932, 0.025434105, -0.023175034, -0.024780531, 
    0.02797402, 0.045557834, 0.070341903), IFOAKTR.LE.Equity = c(-0.109202454, 
    0.077053962, -0.003761378, 0.03465982, 0.065027003, 0.007400809, 
    0.027004966, 0.079149556, -0.012397962, 0.02479647, -0.01164342, 
    0.005031292, 0.008974359, -0.094451504, 0.05940131, -0.12526017, 
    -0.062585623, 0.013383586, -0.054497154, 0.025608092, 0.079602379, 
    0.029870224, 0.022104893, -0.04132516, -0.041382283, -0.020085438, 
    0.032734226, 0.014367178, 0.075052931, -0.022546689, -0.028694504, 
    0.020958512, 0.002171933, -0.006012304, 0.007174005, -0.016131285, 
    0.032436653, -0.069091159, 0.069714201, 0.037003797, 0.015311897, 
    0.015867812, 0.009681792, 0.012913124, 0.058882928, 0.041006079, 
    -0.033779915, 0.0066959, 0.000412031, 0.010002353, -0.007223581, 
    -0.018131675, -0.048526863, -0.05514729, 0.063285249, -0.00806502, 
    0.063090886, 0.035928144, 0.016883191, 0.032305268, 0.006978519, 
    -0.056740661, -0.025714614, -0.033757511, -0.063349796, 0.093672699, 
    0.01333254, -0.019207048, -0.046951731, 0.036508734, 0.043346469, 
    0.043463103, -0.016649961, 0.008154482, 0.081278436, -0.005454545, 
    0.016139984, -0.033155135, -0.030517306, 0.021222923, 0.049028031, 
    0.026516509, 0.001196828, 0.026946257, 0.016344941, -0.035934145, 
    -0.012226512, -0.04004009, 0.035184798, 0.018608169, -0.012475865, 
    0.021406728, 0.026651615, -0.037863938, -0.039403727, -0.006517691, 
    0.045038009, -0.051517114, -0.005568104, -0.000739528, -0.037902416, 
    -0.073956044, -0.041295835, -0.046973635, 0.05331515, 0.022194821, 
    -0.014897467, 0.011449213, -0.03401937, -0.008710365, -0.010114419, 
    -0.037358707, 0.035823272, -0.023184322, 0.005900865), HIMIXFD.GR.Equity = c(0.022534098, 
    0.01962111, -0.03450564, 0.032400589, -0.015977175, -0.012853967, 
    -0.012336009, -0.01704996, -0.034489714, -0.003551285, 0.001886792, 
    0.001987864, 0.025582124, -0.001730808, 0.016114227, 0.016460905, 
    -0.010565814, -0.020459082, -0.005501783, 0.01106444, -0.026041139, 
    -0.010507699, 0.001787404, 0.01154492, 0.023345092, 0.001115279, 
    -0.009925056, -0.006853519, -0.010093727, 0.005930704, 0.000413736, 
    -0.041253102, -0.004529279, 0.006391507, 0.009795479, -0.007994883, 
    -0.010745755, 0.010210732, 0.01688172, 0.002749286, -0.010017927, 
    -0.00308905, 0.016241051, -0.025654505, 0.035933959, 0.001145833, 
    -0.021849964, -0.007126901, -0.005035355, 0.003661032, 0.005149662, 
    0.007044508, -0.000741918, 0.007955028, -0.019677996, -0.008587377, 
    0.012126462, 0.008985879, 0.010920271, 0.000419507, 0.022643883, 
    0.010353665, -0.022524351, -0.004255761, 0.003648494, -0.021292065, 
    -0.020269553, 0.020905546, 0.017718833, 0.005838198, -0.027570481, 
    -0.012577276, -0.001619171, 0.006811547, -0.013530928, -0.023949488, 
    -0.002007584, -0.014863657, -0.014180374, -0.019677791, -0.006925696, 
    0.000591017, -0.013939752, -0.002875285, 0.006848492, -0.013603819, 
    0.002782482, 0.010495838, -0.001790831, -0.007056572, -0.00084317, 
    0.006992164, -0.007422483, 0.013267398, 0.022973456, 0.007796137, 
    0.001039141, 0.007612457, -0.016483516, -0.001163873, -0.000699138, 
    0.024370336, -0.009106431, -0.008960368, 0.014489394, -0.007883912, 
    -0.011056087, -0.03330616, 0.016263101, -0.010431484, 0.007786296, 
    0.00356591, -0.015752695, -0.019614922, -0.017920707), SGAIMPC.FP.Equity = c(0.002215426, 
    -0.000160583, -0.000473671, -0.00011612, -0.00040427, 5.84e-05, 
    0.00235927, 0.040720549, 0.00052727, -0.001635247, 0.000909389, 
    0.00068085, 0.002127684, 3.48e-05, 0.000673515, -0.001937829, 
    9.37e-05, 0.000603557, 0.003919163, 0.000354842, 4.43e-05, 
    8.73e-05, 0.000117884, 4.18e-05, 7.18e-05, 0.000121923, 7.84e-05, 
    4.31e-05, 9.56e-06, -3.83e-05, 9.57e-06, -4.78e-06, 5.98e-07, 
    -2.57e-05, -2.09e-05, -2.93e-05, -7.29e-06, -3.89e-05, 0.003165924, 
    3.75e-05, 3.05e-05, 0.000190651, 0.000223446, 0.000202546, 
    0.000207329, 9.05e-05, 0.000226797, 0.000293002, 0.000313566, 
    0.000143973, 0.000104098, 0.000117112, 0.000101755, 9.28e-05, 
    5.76e-05, 5.6e-05, 4.33e-05, 4.7e-05, 1.66e-05, 2.79e-05, 
    5.35e-06, -2.02e-05, 8.38e-06, -3.39e-05, -4.41e-05, -3.8e-05, 
    -5.7e-05, -0.000101728, -0.000113572, -0.000134993, -0.000177834, 
    -0.000217127, -0.000244544, -0.000203539, -0.000163698, -0.000236954, 
    -0.000267381, -0.000402668, -0.000333706, -0.000344547, -0.00035361, 
    -0.000314962, -0.00035325, -0.000318157, -0.000390508, -0.000359599, 
    -0.000332241, -0.000321591, -0.000330664, -0.000327783, -0.000350029, 
    -0.000325012, -0.000356851, -0.000346797, -0.000379272, -0.000366229, 
    -0.000383752, -0.000362905, -0.000387639, -0.000391991, -0.000341701, 
    0.000816397, -0.000415969, -0.000314659, -0.000365215, -0.0003329, 
    -0.00034383, -0.000377021, -0.00042288, -0.000350844, -0.000350967, 
    -0.000354703, -0.000400614, -0.000466465, -0.000394932), 
    BBVAAGC.SM.Equity = c(-0.000432498, 9.23e-05, -0.000376374, 
    0.002608846, -0.002253214, -0.001642989, 0.003221159, 0.001327248, 
    -0.006231914, 0.000230476, -0.001662934, 0.001091931, 0.002680553, 
    0.000611324, 0.003921341, 0.004239723, 0.001562587, 0.000412201, 
    0.00193408, 0.001346775, 0.00070754, 0.000682471, 0.000299173, 
    0.000900887, -0.000167118, 0.000330658, 0.001403017, -0.000273863, 
    0.000458981, -0.000168639, -7.98e-05, -0.000532343, -0.000217769, 
    0.001257889, -0.000601868, 0.000105209, -1.09e-05, -0.00010792, 
    0.000214956, -0.000180451, 0.000785423, 0.000363403, 1.18e-05, 
    -0.000856078, 0.001165083, -0.000262631, -6.52e-05, 0.000136794, 
    0.000677536, 0.000347591, 0.000125777, 0.000306712, 0.000454952, 
    -0.000345354, 1.54e-05, 7.6e-05, -7.23e-05, 0.000308387, 
    0.000306484, -0.000193415, 8.05e-05, -0.00055048, 0.000108529, 
    -0.00024145, 1.09e-05, 0.000147436, -0.000181781, -2.71e-05, 
    -0.00010674, -0.000313015, -0.000233478, -0.000243489, -0.000165685, 
    5.89e-05, -0.000853868, -0.000364314, -0.00036898, 0, 0.000392696, 
    -0.000661791, -0.001432411, -0.000732223, -0.000861856, -8.92e-05, 
    -0.000619707, -0.000944251, -0.000113928, -0.000847718, -0.000514536, 
    -0.000690965, -0.000227436, -0.000816764, -0.000539469, -0.000841659, 
    -0.001813838, 1.01e-05, -0.002364728, -0.000580171, -8.92e-05, 
    -0.001501542, 0.000716885, -0.000533135, -0.002851352, -0.002105594, 
    -0.001635996, -0.000447924, -0.001719201, 0.000119891, -0.001711734, 
    -0.000454266, -0.001036533, -0.002039791, -0.000356852, 0.00011214, 
    -0.000298073)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -115L
))

    ```

Thank you in advance for you help.
````